# Is "name" attribute mandatory in <input>, <textarea> and <button> elements?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Is `"name"` attribute mandatory in `<input>`, `<textarea>` and `<button>` elements? Or maybe we can use `id` or `class` instead?

Comment: name is not a compulsory attribute. we can use id or class instead...

Comment: instead what? do you mean for accessing control using jquery u want to use id or class ?

Comment: Be carefull that AFAIK, the name attribute is used to correctly name POST variables sent to the server... not the id ! But if that's for client-side use only, better use ID I guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- If these tags are inside a `form` tag and you are subbmitting that
  form to a server, then name is required,
- If you are just using them for client-side purposes and don't want to send them to server, then it is optional.

Answer (score 3):

Name is not a required attribute. A small quote from the [HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fe-name):

> The `name` content attribute gives the name of the form control, as used
>   in form submission and in the form element's elements object. **If** the
>   attribute is specified, its value must not be the empty string.

*Notice the "if" in the quote, indicating that it is not required, from a standards perspective.*

However, if the input is used with the browsers standard form submission, you won't be able to retrieve the value of the input on the server-side, if you don't have a name to refer to.

If you only need to retrieve the value on the client using JavaScript, then you can use an id, a class, or any other means to select the given input - in that case you can leave the name out if desired.

Answer (score 1):

`name` is what gets sent to php scripts for processing so for example `$_POST['Telephone']` when used as `<input name="Telephone" type="text">`. Not required unless being used for processing really.

Answer (score -1):

No its not, but generally you would want it.

Try this

```
<?php
foreach($_GET AS $key=>$val)
{
    echo "name '$key'  has value '$val'<br>";
}
?>
<form>
<input type="text" name="abc">
<input type="text" id="a">
<input type="text" class="b">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```